# different answer when developing Laurent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

given:
$$f(z) = \frac{2}{z^{2}-1}$$
and
$$\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}{a_
{n}(z-2)^{2}}$$
will be the Laurent series of that function.

I've task to calculate the $a_{-3}+a_{2}$

what I've done so far is:
$$\frac{2}{z^2-1}= \frac{1}{z-1}- \frac{1}{z+1}$$
and I got the following sums:
$$\frac{1}{z-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n}\cdot (z-2)^{-n-1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{z+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-3)^{n}\cdot (z-2)^{-n-1}}$$
now, not only I'm not sure how to find $a_{-3}$ and $a_{2}$, but in the official answer the last sum is:
$$\frac{1}{z+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{2}}{3^{n+1}}\cdot(z-2)^{n}}$$
is that matter?

Also, in the official answer didn't told me how to find $a_{-3}$ and $a_{2}$, and why I can use $\sum_{0}^{\infty}$ instead of $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}$?

the official answer is: $a_{-3}+a_{2}=1-\frac{1}{27}=\frac{26}{27}$

Comment: I suspect that in your second equation, the lower limit should be $n = \color{red}{-}\infty$.

Comment: The given function does not have a singularity at $2$. So you must have $a_{-3} = 0$. (This also answers why you can simply use $\sum_0^\infty$.) To compute $a_2$, you can just differentiate twice and find it appropriately.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani "The given function does not have a singularity at 2. So you must have $a_{-3}=0$." can you explain that?

Comment: If you have a complex function that is differentiable on some open neighbourhood of a point, then the function there is given as a power series. In this example, $f$ is well-defined and differentiable on the open circle of radius $1$ centred at $2$. Thus, we can write $f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n(z - 2)^n$. In particular, we don't need any negative index coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Actually $\frac  1{z-1}= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}(z-2)^{n}$.

Also, $\frac 1 {z+1}=\frac 1 {(z-2)+3}=\frac  1 3 \frac 1 {1+\frac {z-2} 3}=\frac  1 3\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (z-2)^{n} (-3)^{-n}$.
$a_{-3}=0$ and you can read out $a_2$ by subtracting the second series from the first and the dividing by $2$.

Comment: but the first sum is : $(-1)^{n} \cdot (z-2)^{-n-1}$, also, what wrong with my second sum? why I can't use it?

Comment: I did a little typo, $\frac{2}{z^{2}-1} = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1}$ so I don't multiply the series

Comment: You are not applying the formula for a geometric sum correctly. $\frac 1 {1+c}=1-c+c^{2}-c^{3}+...$. Take $c=z-2$ for the first one and  $c=\frac {z-2} 3$ for the second.

Comment: The correct answer is $\frac 1 2 [ 1+\frac 1 {27}]=\frac {14} {27}$.  @David

Comment: Rama Murty but this is not the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I figure out my mistake:
this is not true:
$$\frac{1}{z+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-3)^{n}\cdot (z-2)^{-n-1}}$$
since:
$$\frac{1}{z+1} = \frac{1}{(z-2)}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(\frac{-3}{z-2})}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-3)^{n}\cdot (z-2)^{-n-1}}$$
but:
$$\left |\frac{-3}{z-2} \right| >1$$ and therefore, the way i made this series isn't correct.